# After install of Android Studio 3.0.0 - App Build Error: Linking two modules to different data layouts

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

After installing Android Studio 3.0.0 i got the following Warnings:

```
Warning:Linking two modules of different data layouts: 'C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.0\renderscript\lib\bc\armeabi-v7a\libclcore.bc' is 'e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-a:0:32-n32-S64' whereas 'C:\Users\path\debug\raw\saturation.bc' is 'e-p:32:32-i64:64-v128:64:128-n32-S64'

Warning:Linking two modules of different target triples: C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.0\renderscript\lib\bc\mips\libclcore.bc' is 'armv7--linux-android' whereas 'C:\Users\name\path\debug\raw\crossfade.bc' is 'armv7-none-linux-gnueabi'
```

Here my current defaultConfig:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 374
    //necessary for renderscript support
    renderscriptTargetApi 18
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    //to avoid that dex file reached to its maximum method count
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Any ideas how to fix these? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The warnings related to RenderScript "Warning:Linking two modules of different data layouts" are harmless. Feel free to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by enabling adding these lines to my main module

```
renderscriptTargetApi 18
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

It seems all modules using RenderScript and modules which depends on them should have same RenderScript settings in build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio also showed me a lot of errors. Try upgrading all of your SDK files. Beside that, your and mine only solution would be to reinstall AS 3.0 from the scratch.
I did solve my problem, but probably just prolonged it, I'm expecting new error any moment until I completely reinstal AS

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I already installed AS 3.0 from scratch, deleted all related files, the android sdk. The warnings did not disappear.

Comment: Did you go to the folder error message is pointing out? Could it be that you have 2 same files, one from the first AS and another from AS 3.0 ?

Comment: Nope i really deleted all files from the old AS.